# Pandas groupby show only if number of observations more than X

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following code were I group the column prediction with the average of the column confidence and then I sort on the highest 10. I need to have a restriction for number of observations within each group as some of the groups are really small and thus should not come out on top.

prediction_difficulty = master.groupby(['prediction'])['confidence'].mean().reset_index()
prediction_difficulty.sort_values('confidence', ascending=False)[:10]

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I believe need [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
prediction_difficulty.sort_values('confidence',ascending=False).groupby('prediction').head(10)
```

Comment: output is 10 lines like below, which is correct, but some of the group have very little observayions and i only want group were .size() > 25 for example:
87 komondor 0.971406

Comment: @Rob - Unfortunately I have your data, so not sure, what is problem.

Comment: @Rob - Can you create some data sample?